# Exchange2013-x64-SP1 Extending Active Directory schema FAILED

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013

I have problem with Exchange Server 2013, I want to install Exchange 2013 to Windows Server 2012R2.

```
Extending Active Directory schema                         FAILED

C:\Sw>setup.exe /PrepareSchema /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms

Welcome to Microsoft Exchange Server 2013 Service Pack 1 Unattended Setup
Copying Files...
File copy complete. Setup will now collect additional information needed for
installation.

Performing Microsoft Exchange Server Prerequisite Check

    Prerequisite Analysis                                     COMPLETED

Configuring Microsoft Exchange Server

    Extending Active Directory schema                         FAILED
     The following error was generated when "$error.Clear();
        install-ExchangeSchema -LdapFileName ($roleInstallPath + "Setup\Data\"+$
RoleSchemaPrefix + "schema0.ldf")

" was run: "There was an error while running 'ldifde.exe' to import the schema f
ile 'C:\Windows\Temp\ExchangeSetup\Setup\Data\PostWindows2003_schema0.ldf'. The
error code is: 8224. More details can be found in the error file: 'C:\Users\Admi
nistrator\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ldif.err'".


The Exchange Server setup operation didn't complete. More details can be found
in ExchangeSetup.log located in the <SystemDrive>:\ExchangeSetupLogs folder.


info from file:ldif.err

Entry DN: CN=ms-Exch-Access-Control-Map,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=woodgrove,DC=local
Add error on entry starting on line 1: Operations Error
The server side error is: 0x21a2 The FSMO role ownership could not be verified because its directory partition has not replicated successfully with at least one replication partner.
The extended server error is:
000021A2: SvcErr: DSID-030A0B6B, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 8610

An error has occurred in the program
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you have another DC somewhere? Maybe a RODC in a DMZ where schema update is prohibited because of a firewall issue.
You can check for replication issues with this tool: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30005

Comment: If there is no RODC have a look at this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/326262

Answer (score -1):

This error occur when you have a backup dc on your server just remove the second server run rendom /upload

your problem will resolve.